# Validate input field on submission of form before appending it as query strings to the URL

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, woocommerce, query-string

I'm trying to create a custom filter for the price.

```
function abc_filter_price() { 
    global $wp;
    $queryData = array();
    parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $queryData);
    $additional_query = '';
    $min_price = '';
    $max_price = '';
    foreach($queryData as $key => $value){
        if($key !== "min_price" && $key !== "max_price"){
            $additional_query = $additional_query.'<input type="hidden" name="'.$key.'" value="'.$value.'">';   
        }
        if($key === "min_price"){
            $min_price = $value;
        }
        if($key === "max_price"){
            $max_price = $value;
        }
    }
    
    return '
    <form method="get" action="'.home_url($wp->request).'" class="form-filter-by-price">
        <div class="filter-price-form-input-container">
            <input type="number" name="min_price" value="'.$min_price.'" min="1" placeholder="Min"/>
            <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
            <input type="number" name="max_price" value="'.$max_price.'" min="1" placeholder="Max"/>
            '.$additional_query.'
        </div>
        <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
        <button type="submit" name="csx-filter-price"><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
    </form>';
} 
add_shortcode('abc_filter_price', 'abc_filter_price');
```

It's working great, on form submit the `min_price` and `max_price` are added into the query string of the URL.

But there is missing, I need to validate the input from the back-end to avoid empty or zero value.

If the `min_price` or `max_price` is empty or zero, I don't want to add it to the query string.

I'm stock, I don't know what to do next. Anyone can help me out?

Comment: The parameters are added to the query string on the client side, that happens the moment you submit your form. PHP is not even involved at this point. If anything, you will have to do this using _client-side_ validation.

Answer (score 0):

There's a hook `template_redirect`, you can use it to validate the input, for example:

```
function your_redirection(){
    if(isset($_GET['min_price']) || isset($_GET['max_price'])){
            $array = array();
            if(isset($_GET['min_price']) && (empty($_GET['min_price']) || !is_numeric($_GET['min_price']) || (is_numeric($_GET['min_price']) && $_GET['min_price'] < 1))){
                $array[] = "min_price";
            }
            
            if(isset($_GET['max_price']) && (empty($_GET['max_price']) || !is_numeric($_GET['max_price']) || (is_numeric($_GET['max_price']) && $_GET['max_price'] < 1))){
                $array[] = "max_price";
            }
    
            wp_redirect(remove_query_arg($array, false));
        }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'your_redirection' );
```

What happened is:

- When the user submit the form, using `template_redirect` we'll get
  the query using `$_GET`.
- Validate the value of `min_price` and
  `max_price`.
- If `min_price` or `max_price` paramaters exist, then it
  should not be empty, numeric, and not less than 1. Note that this is just a basic condition, you can use your own.
- If the condition is false, then remove the query and redirect back to the same URL.